# Java Utility for Checking Signed JARs

Tags: java, code-signing, jnlp

All,

Is there a good free Java utility that shows you the key that a JAR file was signed by?

I have a number of JAR files referenced in my application - I want to know which ones were signed by the same certificate.

Basically I want to know this as when I am running my JNLP file (hurray!) I am greeted with the message "JAR resources in the JNLP file are not signed by the same certificate".

I have looked at [jar resources in jnlp are not signed by the same certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430755/jar-resources-in-jnlp-are-not-signed-by-the-same-certificate)

I have quite a few JARS so a utility would come in handy.

Edit

The main question is was there a tool that can show me which JARs were signed by which certificate.  Unfortunately the jarsigner tool only tells me if they are signed or not - not by who/what.

Unfortunately I have still not found any tool as yet.

end Edit

Cheers,

Andez

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is just to resign them all with your own key.

Comment: I was hoping my netbeans 7 would be doing this.  I have generated a key and the project output indicates that it has signed all of the files with my key.  However when I run my JNLP file, it begs to differ.

Comment: Consider enabling Java Console and set log level to trace.  This allow you to see the debug messages that javaws gives while loading your application.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at [jarsigner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/jarsigner.html) ?

Comment: Hi Dimitri.  Yes that was the first thing I tried.  However jarsigner -verify -certs myjarfile.jar did not give me real information.

Answer (score 1):

This might be of help [Signed Jar File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Signed%20JAR%20File).

Answer (score 0):

The JDK tool JarSigner is probably that what you are searching for. You find it in the tools.jar. The [sources are availible](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/) if you need a deeper understanding of the signing and verification process.

Also I think it should be possible to use jars with different certs. I didn't test it but perhaps it helps to do something like

```
...
<resources>
    <jar href="jarwithcert1.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources>
    <jar href="jarwithcert2.jar"/>
</resources>
...
```

or

```
...
<resources>
    <jar href="jarwithcert1.jar" part="one" />
    <jar href="jarwithcert2.jar" part="two" />
</resources>
...
```

Comment: @polyurethan - yes I read somewhere that you could do it.  The post I saw was for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/430755/jar-resources-in-jnlp-are-not-signed-by-the-same-certificate.  I have not tried this yet.  But more a case of identifying at the minute thanks andez

Comment: @Andez What did you try? That what I answered or the other solution with an extra jnlp for the other jars?

Comment: @polyurethan - there is a 2 step process.  I found it on http://webstartfaq.com/  You need to do it in 2 files.  

<jar href="myjar1.jar"/>
<extension name="Java Help" href="help.jnlp"/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://ws503" href="Help.jnlp">
     <information>
         <title>JavaHelp</title>
         <vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</vendor>
     </information>
     <resources>
         <jar href="jh.jar"/>
     </resources>
     <component-desc/>
 </jnlp> 

Funnily enough it was the jh.jar file causing the problem.

Comment: I thought I did download a different jh.jar file from here before http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/JKL/Downloadjh2005jar.htm.  This did not have the signing in.  But my initial question was is there a tool for this.  Might spend some time on some code I come across to do this and put it on web somewhere :-/

Comment: Yeah, okay. But that's because I posted the link to the openjdk. There is the source of the JarVerifier. It should be possible to build a tiny tool for checking the certs of all jars. With the URLClassLoader you can get all jar you loaded.
`URLClassLoader cl = (URLClassLoader) Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL[] urls = cl.getURLs();
for (URL url : urls) {
System.out.println(url);
}`